# how to copy directory with wildcard to another folder

Tags: directory, cp

i need to make a cron that copy folder on `/home`

here is the content of my `/home`

```
fina
f-logistik
folder-surat-jalan
zone-A
zone-B
zone-C
zone-free
```

what i need to copy is only folder that start with 'zone'

i've tried :

```
cp /home/zone* /home.bak
```

but return `No such file or directory`

EDIT : and all of the list is folders

EDIT #2 : i use 12.04 precise..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because your `$HOME` is not `/home`. It is a sub-directory of `/home` with the same name as your user. So, if your user name is `mootensai`, your `$HOME` is `/home/mootensai`. To avoid these errors, you can simply use `~` or `$HOME` both of which are your actual home directory. For example, on my system:

```
$ echo ~
/home/terdon
$ echo $HOME
/home/terdon
```

The next problem is that if you are copying multiple files, you want to make sure the last file is a directory. Otherwise, each file you copy will overwrite the last one and you will end up with only one file.

Anyway, the commands you want are:

1. Create the backup directory

   ```
   mkdir ~/backup
   ```
2. Copy the files over

   ```
   cp -r ~/zone* ~/backup
   ```

If, as is most likely the case, you are in your `$HOME`, you can simply do this:

```
cp -r zone* backup
```

Comment: i've tried cp zone* backup, but return "No such file or directory"  when i'm at /home

Comment: @moo.tensai that's because you're at `/home` and not at `/home/mootensai`. Forget `/home`, that is not your home directory, think of it as the `/Users` directory on OSX or  `C:\Users` on Windows. Your actual home directory is a sub directory of that.

Comment: @moo.tensai if your sources are also directories, make sure to use `-r` (see updated answer).

Comment: i've tried 'cp -r zone* /home.bak' but still return no such file or directory..

Comment: @moo.tensai please use one of the commands I suggested. For example `cp -r ~/zone* ~/home.bak`. That will work **as long as the ~/home.bak directory exists**. You can't copy directories into a directory that doesn't exist. Try running the _exact_ 2 commands I gave you, step 1 and step 2.

Comment: actually i login as root, and i dont have folder "/home/mootensai"

Comment: i've tried : cp -r ~/zone* ~/home.bak but return 'cp: cannot stat `/root/zone*': No such file or directory'

Comment: @moo.tensai OK, that's a completely different thing, please **don't log in as root**! No offense, but it does not sounds like you are very experienced in the command line and playing around as root can easily break your system. Don't do it. Anyway. I don't know where the directories you need are, you need to use the right path. Assuming they are in the home directory of whichever user you are using, the commands I gave will work. Just use them: `mkdir ~/backup` and `cp -r ~/zone* ~/backup`.

Comment: @moo.tensai If you want your backup directory to be called `home.bak`, then do this: `mkdir ~/home.bak` and then this `cp -r ~/zone* ~/home.bak`.

Comment: i've tried : cp -r ~/zone* ~/backup and still returns
cp: cannot stat `/home/mootensai/zone*': No such file or directory please help...

Comment: HI! it's working!!!!thx a lot!!